# Include all java files which are in a folder of a specific pattern?

Tags: regex, gradle

I have a task which builds a source jar and excludes all folders matching the pattern `**/*processor*`:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from(sourceSets.main.allSource) {
    exclude '**/*processor*'
  }
}
```

When I modify the former task to include all java files which are in folders which match the pattern `**/*processor*`:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
  classifier = 'sources'
  from(sourceSets.main.allSource) {
    include '**/*processor*'
  }
}
```

then I get a result which contains all files not only the files in folders which math the pattern.

How can I include all files which are in a folder of a specific pattern?

Comment: Do you mean that your program includes all files from that directory recursively?

Comment: @ChakerMallek Yes all files from all directories which match the pattern recursively

Comment: @Pshemo It might include regex

Comment: Maybe that will sound silly, but what happens if you `exclude '**'` before including? If the first case worked, it means it includes everything by default, then applies the exclude rule. Now if you only provide an include rule, it will include everything, and then include a subset of everything, which is not very useful. I tried to look at the only documentation before posting this, but couldn't quickly find anything going for or against my theory.